# Couldn't find a differ for type: [B

Tags: java, object, diff

I am using Daniel Bechler algorithm to compare objects. 
[Github Source](https://github.com/SQiShER/java-object-diff)

I am getting the following error message when I have blob in my objects.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't find a differ for type: [B
    at de.danielbechler.diff.differ.DifferProvider.retrieveDifferForType(DifferProvider.java:47)
    at de.danielbechler.diff.differ.DifferDispatcher.compare(DifferDispatcher.java:182)
    at de.danielbechler.diff.differ.DifferDispatcher.compareWithCircularReferenceTracking(DifferDispatcher.java:158)
    at de.danielbechler.diff.differ.DifferDispatcher.compare(DifferDispatcher.java:145)
    at de.danielbechler.diff.differ.DifferDispatcher.dispatch(DifferDispatcher.java:93)
    at de.danielbechler.diff.differ.BeanDiffer.compareUsingIntrospection(BeanDiffer.java:114)
    at de.danielbechler.diff.differ.BeanDiffer.compareUsingAppropriateMethod(BeanDiffer.java:104)
    at de.danielbechler.diff.differ.BeanDiffer.compare(BeanDiffer.java:90)
    at de.danielbechler.diff.differ.DifferDispatcher.compare(DifferDispatcher.java:188)
    at de.danielbechler.diff.differ.DifferDispatcher.compareWithCircularReferenceTracking(DifferDispatcher.java:158)
    at de.danielbechler.diff.differ.DifferDispatcher.compare(DifferDispatcher.java:145)
    at de.danielbechler.diff.differ.DifferDispatcher.dispatch(DifferDispatcher.java:93)
    at de.danielbechler.diff.ObjectDiffer.compare(ObjectDiffer.java:49)
    at com.sil.ehealth.server.resource.DoctorResource.syncDoc(DoctorResource.java:66)
    at com.sil.ehealth.server.resource.DoctorResource.mergeDoc(DoctorResource.java:159)
    at com.sil.ehealth.server.resource.DoctorResource$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e1efd1d4.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
    at com.sil.ehealth.server.resource.DoctorResource$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$505d2b09.mergeDoc(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:151)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:171)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:152)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:387)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:331)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:103)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:254)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1028)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:377)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:221)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:176)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Glad if someone can help. How to cater for this issue? I really need to compare the objects with blob

Method to convert byte[] to list

```
  public List<Byte> byteArrayToList(byte[] byteArray){
    List<Byte> list = new ArrayList<Byte>();
    for(byte b : byteArray){
      list.add(new Byte(b));
    }
    return list;
  }
```

The following codes is where the comparison is done:

```
  public Response compareObject(Car workingCar)
    Car baseCar = carDao.getById(workingCar.getCarId());
    if (null!=baseCar){
        byteArrayToList(workingCar.getcarImg()));
        byteArrayToList(baseCar.getcarImg());
        DiffNode diff = ObjectDifferBuilder.buildDefault().compare(workingCar, baseCar);
        diff.visit(new DiffNode.Visitor() {
        @Override
        public void node(DiffNode node, Visit visit) {
            try {

                /**
                 * Object has been modified , update base on most recent
                 * 
                 */
            }
     //some codes here
```

Comment: I've updated the post. Well am using the exact algo.

Comment: Obviously it's because the algo is not supporting `byte[]`. But it seems to support Collections. So you could convert `byte[]` to `List<Byte>` and then use it.

Comment: someone has already opened a issue: https://github.com/SQiShER/java-object-diff/issues/141

Comment: @wero It's my friend!

Comment: @asma then I don't understand why you posted the question on stackoverflow

Comment: I want views of some other people. Who knows he'll reply on github!

Comment: @Codebender I try to convert it to list and it continues to give this error message. pls see updated post to see the method converting byte[] to list

Comment: @asma, put the error stacktrace when you pass `List<Byte>`. Because I can see `CollectionDiffer.java` which should be able to handle `List`.

Comment: I am getting the same stack trace as above

Comment: @Codebender See updated post . I've added the method where I am doing the conversion and send it for comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a lengthy explanation about this issue just a few days ago in the java-object-diff issue tracker: https://github.com/SQiShER/java-object-diff/issues/143

In short: Arrays are not yet supported. But as mentioned in the comments, converting your Array to a Collection should work. At least as long as you don't care about item order or duplicate items.

Alternatively (as a workaround) you can try to use the extension mechanisms of the library to add your own custom Differ, that adds Array-support the way you need it, until it's officially supported.

More information how to do that can be found in the link above. Feel free to ask any further questions in the official issue tracker. I promise, I'll respond. ;-)

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Actually it's a byte of array containing an image. I think the order is important such that when convert back to byte can reproduce the image. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, the order is very important in that case. When you are dealing with an image, I would assume, you only really care whether the images has changed and not which bytes have changed, right? In that case you could simply write a custom ByteArrayDiffer. I just tested it out and it works like a charm. You can find my quick and dirty implementation [here](https://gist.github.com/SQiShER/dc5d456a9d39dd1c8e60).

Comment: Yes I'm concern only if the image has changed. Thanks for your support.