# Error while intercepting a hibernate event

Tags: java, hibernate

My goal is to find out what columns where changed during an update on my MySQL database. 
My first idea was to use the Hibernate Event System. I have implemented a `PreUpdateEventListener`. The event allows access to the changed object and I'm retrieving the older object from the database. I am using the [Java Object Diff Library](https://github.com/SQiShER/java-object-diff) to compare the two objects. Since I only need the first layer to be compared I configured the Comparator as follows:

```
public static List<String> compareTillFirstLayer(Object pre, Object post) {
    ArrayList<String> changedProperties = new ArrayList<String>();
    InclusionResolver inclusionResolver = new InclusionResolver() {

        @Override
        public Inclusion getInclusion(DiffNode node) {
            if (node.getParentNode().isRootNode()) {
                return Inclusion.INCLUDED;
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean enablesStrictIncludeMode() {
            return true;
        }
    };
    ObjectDiffer objectDiffer = ObjectDifferBuilder.startBuilding().inclusion().resolveUsing(inclusionResolver)
            .and().build();
    DiffNode root = objectDiffer.compare(pre, post);
    root.visitChildren(new DiffNode.Visitor() {
        @Override
        public void node(DiffNode node, Visit visit) {
            changedProperties.add(node.getPropertyName());
        }
    });
    return changedProperties;
}
```

This returns the changed properties of the object. To find the connection to the database columns I use the Hibernate Configuration and it's mapping like this:

```
for (String property : changedProperties) {
            PersistentClass persistentClass = HibernateUtil.getHibernateUtil().getConfiguration()
                    .getClassMapping(Consumer.class.getName());
            String columnName = ((Column) persistentClass.getProperty(property).getColumnIterator().next())
                    .getName();
            System.out.println(columnName);
        }
```

This workes just fine for my `Consumer` object but it fails with other objects like an `Appointment` or a `Vehicle` object.
Even the exceptions differ from object to object. 
If I try to monitor the changes of the `Appointment` I recieve the following exception:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:854)
    at de.applicodata.serviceportal.persistence.hibernateEventListeners.PreUpdateEventImpl.onPreUpdate(PreUpdateEventImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityUpdateAction.preUpdate(EntityUpdateAction.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:383)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:133)
    at de.applicodata.serviceportal.persistence.dao.GeneralDAO.commit(GeneralDAO.java:189)
    at de.applicodata.serviceportal.persistence.dao.GeneralDAO.update(GeneralDAO.java:556)
    at de.applicodata.serviceportal.logic.entities.Appointment.updatePersistenceObject(Appointment.java:167)
    at de.applicodata.serviceportal.faces.beans.MyAppointmentsBean.updateAppointmemt(MyAppointmentsBean.java:777)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:279)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:273)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at net.bull.javamelody.JsfActionListener.processAction(JsfActionListener.java:67)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:239)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at de.applicodata.serviceportal.faces.listener.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:36)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at de.applicodata.serviceportal.faces.listener.SessionTimeoutFilter.doFilter(SessionTimeoutFilter.java:129)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1136)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

While monitoring changes on the `Vehicle` object I receiver the following exception although the Objects are diffrent from another:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't find a differ for type: [B
    at de.danielbechler.diff.differ.DifferProvider.retrieveDifferForType(DifferProvider.java:55)
    at de.danielbechler.diff.differ.DifferDispatcher.compare(DifferDispatcher.java:196)
    at de.danielbechler.diff.differ.DifferDispatcher.compareWithCircularReferenceTracking(DifferDispatcher.java:172)
    at de.danielbechler.diff.differ.DifferDispatcher.compare(DifferDispatcher.java:159)
    at de.danielbechler.diff.differ.DifferDispatcher.dispatch(DifferDispatcher.java:105)
    at de.danielbechler.diff.differ.BeanDiffer.compareUsingIntrospection(BeanDiffer.java:114)
    at de.danielbechler.diff.differ.BeanDiffer.compareUsingAppropriateMethod(BeanDiffer.java:104)
    at de.danielbechler.diff.differ.BeanDiffer.compare(BeanDiffer.java:90)
    at de.danielbechler.diff.differ.DifferDispatcher.compare(DifferDispatcher.java:202)
    at de.danielbechler.diff.differ.DifferDispatcher.compareWithCircularReferenceTracking(DifferDispatcher.java:172)
    at de.danielbechler.diff.differ.DifferDispatcher.compare(DifferDispatcher.java:159)
    at de.danielbechler.diff.differ.DifferDispatcher.dispatch(DifferDispatcher.java:105)
    at de.danielbechler.diff.ObjectDiffer.compare(ObjectDiffer.java:52)
    at de.applicodata.serviceportal.persistence.hibernateEventListeners.HibernateEventObjectComparator.compareTillFirstLayer(HibernateEventObjectComparator.java:34)
    at de.applicodata.serviceportal.persistence.hibernateEventListeners.PreUpdateEventImpl.onPreUpdate(PreUpdateEventImpl.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityUpdateAction.preUpdate(EntityUpdateAction.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:383)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:133)
    at de.applicodata.serviceportal.persistence.dao.GeneralDAO.commit(GeneralDAO.java:189)
    at de.applicodata.serviceportal.persistence.dao.GeneralDAO.update(GeneralDAO.java:556)
    at de.applicodata.serviceportal.logic.entities.Vehicle.updatePersistenceObject(Vehicle.java:509)
    at de.applicodata.serviceportal.faces.beans.WerWiSalesVehicleBean.updateVehicle(WerWiSalesVehicleBean.java:1892)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:279)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:273)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at net.bull.javamelody.JsfActionListener.processAction(JsfActionListener.java:67)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:239)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at de.applicodata.serviceportal.faces.listener.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:36)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at de.applicodata.serviceportal.faces.listener.SessionTimeoutFilter.doFilter(SessionTimeoutFilter.java:129)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:494)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1136)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I really don't know where to start on this one since the exceptions are so different from eachother. Any tips on what might cause this behaviour are appreciated!
If any further information is needed I'll provide it. 
Edit: The `Vehicle` error is kind of resolved. It was due to a missing feature in the before mentioned Java Object Diff Library. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32451705/couldnt-find-a-differ-for-type-b)
 I am currently working on a workaround for excluding arrays from the comparison

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first part of the question is answered. Due to the Java Object Diff Library not beeing able to work with arrays I decided to just exclude these from the comparison.
This works just fine with the rewritten `compareTillFirstLayer` method like this:

```
public class HibernateEventObjectComparator {

    public final static InclusionResolver inclusionResolver = new InclusionResolver() {

        @Override
        public Inclusion getInclusion(DiffNode node) {
            if (node.getParentNode().isRootNode() && node.getValueType().isArray()) {
                return Inclusion.EXCLUDED;
            } else if (node.getParentNode().isRootNode()) {
                return Inclusion.INCLUDED;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean enablesStrictIncludeMode() {
            return true;
        }
    };

    public static List<String> compareTillFirstLayer(Object pre, Object post) {
        ArrayList<String> changedProperties = new ArrayList<String>();

        ObjectDiffer objectDiffer = ObjectDifferBuilder.startBuilding().inclusion().resolveUsing(inclusionResolver)
                .and().build();
        DiffNode root = objectDiffer.compare(pre, post);
        root.visitChildren(new DiffNode.Visitor() {
            @Override
            public void node(DiffNode node, Visit visit) {
                changedProperties.add(node.getPropertyName());
            }
        });
        return changedProperties;
    }
...
```

EDIT: The second problme is solved as well. 
The list of columns I got from hibernate was empty if it referred to a collection. Since I didn't need these columns I'm simply checking if a column is availabe and only iterate over the columns array if there are columns inside. Sadly I have no answer to why the columns array for any collection is empty.